# Getting a warning when i opened my xcode 4.5 project in xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, nib

I am getting this warning when i opened my project in xcode 5.

```
Multiple resources have the same name: .png. The preceding issues may have occurred due to an SCM operation such as merging.
```

In my XIB i have 2 uiimageviews with the same background image.

Comment: what you did with this warning?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. can you state how you solved it ?

Comment: Hello try to see if you have 2 pngs with same name in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the images which caused error in your project , and restart Xcode, relink the image resource.